# Is it possible to seek file list in a certain public-directory from HTML/javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I plan to implement module component system (plugin) for node.js client side.

For instance(simplified),

```
/www/index.html
     index.js
     modules/moduleA/module.js
                     some.html

             moduleB/....
             .....
```

It's surely possible to hardcode the list of module dir-names, and `require` (with browserify) components, but I would rather point them automatically depending on the modules directory structure.

In node.js, I do this easily as

```
var modules;
fs.readdir('./www/modules', function(err, modulesDir)
{
  var modules = [];
  modulesDir.map(function(modulename)
  {
    modules[modulename] = require('./www/modules/' + modulename + '/module');
  });
}
```

However, in the client side, even with `browserify`, since `fs` is basically not supported in the browser side, the same manner is not possible as far as I tried.

How can we achieve to read through directory names under a certain directory path?

Thanks.

PS. I just found 
https://github.com/brianloveswords/filesystem-browserify
but it looks a bit old, if you have a good recommendation, please let me know.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just create a web service method that returns the file list (or pass via templating engine)? Is that prohibited by the plug-in architecture? That seems easiest -- since client will not have access to the filesystem there will always need to be some complementary server component involved.

Comment: Nothing is prohibited, I just try to build an architecture easily maintained. File-list is straight-forward and easy implementation, but for a long run, we need to track the module-addition-deletion reflecting to the list, and it'seasily forgotten (extra maintenance glitch). So since, for server side, require-automatically walking the module directory is possible, I wonder if there's a way to implement in the exact same manner. thanks!

Comment: @jim0, I got it! You are right. I can pass the dir list data from node server via socket.io

Comment: yep, same concept (but i havent used socket.io yet, on my to-do list). in node i mostly make static html/React.js apps & pass data by making ajax calls to RESTful json services